# How do I send request headers?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, http-headers

How do I send request headers ? Suppose I want to send my own request header when I make an HTTP request to a website.

How do I do that ?

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// HOW DO I SEND REQUEST HEADER LIKE Date,Cookie,Cache-Control ???
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
connection.setRequestProperty("HeaderName", "Value");
```

Answer (score 2):

After getting the HttpURLConnection connection, you can do that as follows

```
//adding headers
con.setRequestProperty("headername", value);
```